# Oauth 2.0 authorization using JWT

Tags: oauth-2.0, authorization, asp.net-web-api2, jwt

I am implementing in web api 2  authorization using **JWT** token and I am new to this space. 
I am stick to the purpose of generating **AudienceId** and **AudienceSecret** why I need them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the perspective of OAuth, the tokens are opaque objects and does not contain 'audience' claims. If you use JWT tokens, then you can refer to JWT specificacion RFC7159

> **4.1.3.  "aud" (Audience) Claim**
>
> **The "aud" (audience) claim identifies the recipients that the JWT is
>      intended for**.  Each principal intended to process the JWT MUST
>      identify itself with a value in the audience claim.  If the principal
>      processing the claim does not identify itself with a value in the
>      "aud" claim when this claim is present, then the JWT MUST be
>      rejected.  In the general case, the "aud" value is an array of case-
>      sensitive strings, each containing a StringOrURI value.  In the
>      special case when the JWT has one audience, the "aud" value MAY be a
>      single case-sensitive string containing a StringOrURI value.  The
>      interpretation of audience values is generally application specific.
>      Use of this claim is OPTIONAL.

The intended use  of `aud`is to identify intended recipients of the token. Its use is optional and depends on the context of the application. May be in the documentation of your Oauth2 server is specified the purpose

Take also a look to this detailed [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41237822/6371459) about this topic