# Jwt with new client

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oauth, owin, startup

I have implemented JWT auth

I have function in startup file like

```
public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            var issuer = "http://jwtauthzsrv.azurewebsites.net";
            //var audience = "fd9eeeb25b694ff1bfd2260cf0d665c3";
            //var secret = TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode("ixioSD5UPMMfGFUvxfblU3elZAnUvtoleVI0qu_7SrI");
            List<string> secret = new List<string>();
            List<string> audience = new List<string>();

            secret.Add(Convert.ToBase64String(TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode("adFu3IhHjNibtVzy7Uon7l9CQE97XQ8YOKnLzLWlb1s")));
            //secret.Add(Convert.ToBase64String(TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode("YqnwwJFI6HTQheAGvHI9ycuhgRmkpJDgOQDkDnahG2I")));
            // secretkeys.Add(TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode("YqnwwJFI6HTQheAGvHI9ycuhgRmkpJDgOQDkDnahG2I").ToString());
            audience.Add("746b0e9e0bb44bfda086bc7f03f427c5");
           // audience.Add("7ef27cd3397d41e4848c3a85cca9e737");





            // Api controllers with an [Authorize] attribute will be validated with JWT
            app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
                new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
                    AllowedAudiences =  audience.AsEnumerable(),//new[] { audience },
                    //AllowedAudiences = new[] { audience },
                    IssuerSecurityTokenProviders = new IIssuerSecurityTokenProvider[]
                    {
                        new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityTokenProvider(issuer, secret)
                        //new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityTokenProvider(issuer,secret.AsEnumerable())
                    },
                    Provider = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider
                    {
                        OnValidateIdentity = context =>
                        {
                            context.Ticket.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("newCustomClaim", "newValue"));
                            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
                        }
                    }
                });

        }
```

I assume whenever an api with **authorize** attribue is being called it should call `ConfigureOAuth` so that it should load all cient id from database and validate through jwt, but while debugging I saw startup file runs only when I run the application,

How can I make this to call `ConfigureOAuth` this function whenever any api getting called, so that it should load new clientid as well and validate.

**UPDATE**

```
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
                new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
                    AllowedAudiences =  select from database),
```

the above line is being initialized only once when I publish and deploy project, but not when a new api call is being made.

Problem occurring if a new user has been created, the id of new user is not coming in allowed audiences

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`ConfigureOAuth` should only run once at startup, so the behavior is correct.

With `app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication` you add a middleware for authentication to the request pipeline. You already add the allowed audiences to the configuration, so it won't be loaded again during processing of an `[Authorize]` decorated api. The middleware will then check for the presence of an authorization header in the request and check if the provided JWT is valid and the audience matches the configured audiences.

Update in reaction to your update:

> Problem occurring if a new user has been created, the id of new user is not coming in allowed audiences

"Audiences" are not the users, but the resource servers for which the token can be used, see also here: [JWT (Json Web Token) Audience "aud" versus Client_Id - What's the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28418360/jwt-json-web-token-audience-aud-versus-client-id-whats-the-difference)

And the user authentication doesn't happen when you process a request which is decorated with `[Authorize]` but already much earlier when the user requests a token at the token endpoint. The JWT auth middleware will only check if the token that it finds in the Authorization header of the request has an aud value that matches the AllowedAudiences. But at this point, the user is already authenticated.

The place where you access your user database would be in a different class, e.g

```
public class MyAuthProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
    public override Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
    if(Authenticate(context.UserName, context.Password))
        ...
    }
}
```

That's where you authenticate the user, add claims to the JWT and finally create the JWT token.

I recommend reading Taiseer Joudehs blog: http://bitoftech.net/2015/02/16/implement-oauth-json-web-tokens-authentication-in-asp-net-web-api-and-identity-2/

Comment: For example I have given value hardcoded but those are loading audience from database.

Comment: it doesn't matter from where you get the audiences, with `app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication( new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions { AllowedAudiences =`  you tell the middleware which audiences are allowed and the JWT will be checked against these configured audiences.

Comment: but it's still only a one time configuration, the actual processing of a call is done by the middleware

Comment: if I do app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication( new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions { AllowedAudiences = list
So  the new list will be bind in each  api call having authorize attribute