# Securing a restful API verifying clients with JWT

Tags: rest, security, jwt

I have a RESTful API using JWT for authentication purposes. The first call I receive from a client is the /login call, with the following payload (no headers)

```
{
     "username" : xxxx,
     "password": wwww
}
```

The server verifies if the user is registered and then returns a signed JWT to the client in order to be received in the next calls.

I wonder if this is secure enough. I don't check anywhere if the client sends me a client id / client secret (like in OAuth) so I cannot verify if this call is from my webapp / apps or if it is an external client which I don't know about. I want to know if it makes sense to implement this behavior using JWT and how to implement it.

(I know how to do it with OAuth2 but I don't want to move now from JWT authentication)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you should create a function somewhat similar to this:

```
function verify(req, res, next) {
   const token = req.header('x-auth-token');

   if (!token) {
       return res.status(401).json({
           msg: 'No token, auth denied'
       });
  }

   try {
       const decoded = jwt.verify(token, config.get(YOUR_SECRET_GOES_HERE));
       req.user = decoded.user;
       next();
   } catch (err) {
       res.status(401).json({
           msg: 'Token is not valid'
       });
   }
}
```

For all secured API endpoints you should apply it like this:

```
router.get('/anyuserinfo', verify, (req, res) => ...
```

And that is it. The function will send `401` response if no token is provided.

Comment: I think here you are verifying if this JWT was generated by this server checking its secret. But I was thinking of the first login call. Imagine you want to restrict that all API calls are done by known clients (in OAuth you would give them a client_id and client_secret). 
I was asking if there is something similar using JWT auth.

Comment: I'm still not sure if I can understand you. You can add a payload to JWT. The payload can be of any type you like. So it is possible to add an object with info for verification into the token that you issue and then decode it as I have shown above(decoded.user is the payload). If that is not what you need - then I'm a little bit slow)

Comment: Yes, you are right in this case. But think of the first /login api call. No JWT is issued yet so you can't do that. I want to check in this case (and in the following api calls) if the client is known by the server. I was thinking of this: https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/06/29/what-is-the-oauth2-password-grant
(see the client_id part) but I don't know If it is ok to do this with JWT. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I think I found another Stackoverflow question that answers mine:
[JWT (Json Web Token) Audience "aud" versus Client_Id - What's the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28418360/jwt-json-web-token-audience-aud-versus-client-id-whats-the-difference)

In a nutshell, client_id and client_secret should be sent on headers to the server to be validated before sending a new JWT token.