# Can SSO token from one app be validated in another app?

Tags: azure-active-directory, single-sign-on

I am building an app which has backend services (API) and also a frontend (UI) to manage the overall application.

- Both the frontend and backend will be using the same Azure AD app registration(APP1).
- The UI will be secured via Azure AD SSO.
- When the UI makes a call to the API, the ID token will be sent in the header
- The API will validate the token before servicing the call. If the validation fails, an exception is returned.

There are other UI applications which will integrate with the API to use the product. These applications are registered under different Azure AD apps (App2) and are also secured by SSO.

Both App2 and App1 are in the same Azure Tenant.

My question is, If a user logs into App2 and gets a ID token and sends the ID token in the header of the API call to App1, can we verify the validity of the token in App1? If yes, can you share some code samples?

If the other UI applications are using SSO with Azure AD in the same tenant, I would like to have them send the ID token, otherwise a client credential grant flow(AccessToken) would be acceptable.

I am in the design phase of the application so I have not written any code to verify if it is possible. I saw a few code sample which talked about validating via private keys, but I do not think private keys of one app will be accessible to another app.
I am trying to figure out the best way to authenticate users when there are multiple Azure AD app registrations involved.

Comment: Therre is no such term as an "SSO token" (in both SAML and OAuth/OIDC) so I'm unsure exactly what you're referring to. Please use correct and precise terminology.

Comment: @Dai I mean an ID token.

Comment: "_Both the frontend and backend will be using the same Azure AD app registration(APP1)._" - that doesn't sound right to me - if the fronternd is just the UI then it doesn't need any registration at all - and registration involves secrets-registration, and secrets shouldn't be shared - so that's another reason.

Comment: In OIDC an `id_token` is not an `access_token` - they're different things for different purposes (also, only OIDC has `id_token`, while OAuth does not have `id_token`, only `access_token`).

Comment: _"When the UI makes a call to the API, the ID token will be sent in the header"_ - you mean you're using Bearer tokens in the HTTP `Authorization:` header?

Comment: _"can we verify the validity of the token in App1?"_ - what constitutes validity, exactly? there's lots of things to consider (`aud`, `expires`, signature checks, etc) - is this a structured JWT token or an opaque reference-token?

Comment: The frontend will use the client id, client secret etc to redirect a user to login.microsoftonline.com and get the ID token. So technically, it will be using the same Azure AD app.

Comment: _"If the other UI applications are using SSO with Azure AD in the same tenant, I would like to have them send the ID token, otherwise a client credential grant flow(AccessToken) would be acceptable."_ - I can't think of any good reason to do this - what problem are you facing that you're trying to solve with this approach? [You **do** know that the `aud` claim exists to _prevent_ applications from doing this...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28418360/jwt-json-web-token-audience-aud-versus-client-id-whats-the-difference)

Comment: _"The frontend will use the client id, client secret etc to redirect a user to login.microsoftonline.com and get the ID token. So technically, it will be using the same Azure AD app."_ - yikes **DO NOT DO THAT** (exposing `client_credentials`, etc) - that's horribly wrong and insecure

Comment: "you mean you're using Bearer tokens in the HTTP Authorization: header?" -- I am sure I am not using the correct terminology, but essentially what I am trying to do is verify that a the user making the API call is logged in and the that the ID token is a valid one. 
Validity constitutes, 1) is this token something that was issued by an app in this Azure AD tenant. 2) is it expired or not.

Comment: ...also, whern using `client_credentials` (in OIDC and OAuth) clients communicate directly with the token-endpoint - and never involves human users interacting with a login form in a browser - they're different use-cases: `client_credentials` is intended for human-user-less headless clients and services - if a human user is involved then you don't/can't use `client_credentials`.

Comment: Just use the official AAD libraries as they manage token lifetimes, validity, and reissuing them for you.

Comment: I plan on using the MSAL library, the client id and secret will be stored in a keyvault. I took a look at this sample application provided by MSFT: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-java-webapp/tree/master/msal-java-webapp-sample for implementing SSO, so I will be using the offical AAD libraries.

Comment: ...you can't use Azure Keyvault to store client-secrets because the client won't be able to access the Keyvault without first authenticating which requires said client-secret... also you really shouldn't be storing client-secrets _anywhere_ except _on the client_ itself, and ideally protected using something like DPAPI's local-machine mode.

Comment: Got it, I guess I have a bit more of reading to do. One other option (instead of secrets) is certificate, I will explore that.
I guess you have understood the problem I am trying to solve, can you provide any directions on that?

Comment: I guess - I think you should delete this question for now, do your further reading, then post a new SO question if you're unsure about anything.

Comment: Thank you for the conversation @Dai. I see value in having this question for other folks who may come down the same path. I have answered the question based on your responses. If you'd rather provide an answer indicating the same, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ID token will have the "aud" field to indicate who the intended audience of the token is. If an app gets a token and the "aud" field does not match its own application id, then the token must be rejected.

So, the token from from app cannot be used in another app.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/id-tokens